# Dynamic Button with Lottie animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibutton

I have a simple `UIButton` with a `title`:

```
let signUpButton: CustomButton = {
    let v = CustomButton(type: .system)
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.setTitle("Registrieren", for: .normal)
    v.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 15)
    v.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
    v.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(signUpButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return v
}()
```

Now my goal is that when the button is tapped, the `title` disappears, the `button` should not longer be clickable and a `loading-animation` (Lottie)  should be displayed. 
There are two options after the click:

1. Everything is fine, data is being retrieved and I `present` another `ViewController`
2. some error occured, `loading-animation` disappears, `title` is displayed again

This is my `buttonTapped`-function so far (not complete function for simplicity):

```
@objc func signUpButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let logoAnimation = AnimationView(name: "LoadingAnimation")
    logoAnimation.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    logoAnimation.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(logoAnimation)

    logoAnimation.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signUpButton.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    logoAnimation.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signUpButton.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    logoAnimation.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    logoAnimation.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    logoAnimation.loopMode = .loop
    logoAnimation.play()

    if error!= nil {
      logoAnimation.stop()
      logoAnimation.removeFromSuperView()
    } else {
          /* present new VC */ 
    }
```

Now, the actual question is, how do I make the `title` appear/disappear and what can I do so the `button` is not clickable while "loading"?

I thought about creating a `UIView` with the exact same size/color of the button and placing that on top of the `button` but that seems not very clean and smart..

Is there a quick and easy way to get this done?
Grateful for every help :) If you need more details just let me know.

Comment: isn't `logoAnimation` above the button according to constraints

Comment: yes it is. But on purpose? I want it to be displayed. Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to hide button

```
btn.setTitle("", for: .normal)
```

or

```
btn.isHidden = true
```

Comment: ok that was waaay easier than I thought... `setTitle` works perfeclty. Thanks!